# Fuzzy image display on new content type

Tags: media

I'm having issues on our Drupal 7 site. We have created a new content type that includes a hero image. The problem is that full sized images that we upload aren't displayed on the page (despite calling for "Original image" in the manage display settings.

[image]

Instead, the page is displaying the image in Drupal's "large" image style, then scaling up on the page and creating a blurry image.

Here's a test page: https://claremontmckdev.prod.acquia-sites.com/content/history-0

Comment: There must be something overriding the field settings, very difficult to say what that is without seeing the code. Check your theme/templates and custom modules first, also make sure the page isn’t built with panels or something. Those are the sort of things to check

Comment: Do you have some code that is dealing that handles displaying either a video or an image on the page?  Maybe in the theme or template file?

Comment: Thanks. I think you are both on the right track. There is code that displays either a video or image on the page. I have checked the template code but couldn't find the issue (then thought it might be a simple setting within the D7 dashboard). I'll look at the code again.

Comment: Here's a code snippet from a default.inc custom module file. I can't see anything amiss here though....

$pane->configuration = array(
    'label' => 'title',
    'formatter' => 'picture_sizes_formatter',
    'delta_limit' => '0',
    'delta_offset' => '0',
    'delta_reversed' => 0,
    'formatter_settings' => array(
      'image_link' => '',
      'fallback_image_style' => '_original image_',
      'sizes' => '400',
      'image_styles' => array(
        'large' => 'large',
 ...... 


    ),
    ),

Answer (score 0):

Based on the markup on your test page reflecting an html5  element and the code snippet calling for a "picture_sizes_formatter", I suspect your site has the [Picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) and [Breakpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/breakpoints) module) installed which automatically serve images based on predefined/configured breakpoints.

Go to the Picture Mappings configuration page *Config >
 Media > Picture Mappings* (/admin/config/media/picture) to examine existing mappings and add new ones.
[image: picture mapping config link from configuration page]

You should be able to add a new picture mapping for a wider breakpoint to serve the original image, thus limiting serving the large image to a narrower desktop viewport.

Once you've added an additional mapping (and possibly a wide breakpoint), don't forget to clear the caches before reloading your test page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @anson-w-han. We do have the Picture and Breakpoint modules but I don't think that's the issue. Checked the mappings and we only have the three defaults for Event image, Footer block and Media block there. Also photos uploaded in other content types don't have the issue (for instance https://claremontmckdev.prod.acquia-sites.com/news/can-science-solve-problems-of-fair-pay-and-hiring-prof-jeffrey-flory-leading-research-to-find).

Tested by creating a new mapping with settings to hopefully override the issue but it had no effect.

Comment: The image in your production site news story example doesn't look to be rendered with the same markup (<picture> tag).  It may be worth checking the content type template or even a pane template to see if they are specifically calling for a particular picture size format rule (which would explain why it disregards your new mapping setting).

Comment: That was my instinct too -- settings in the content type ask for display of the original image -- but I think the override it's buried deep in the code. The developer used the Features module to create and display this content item. I'm going to pursue that theory and will report back if I solve it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In the off chance that anyone else is struggling with this issue, we were able to solve the conundrum. The pages were created via panels and the formatter settings for the image within the panel settings were set to "picture." Changed that to "Image" and all was copacetic.

[image]